# Merging two lists into one by dates

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists of Slots

```
public class Slot
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }

    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    public List<Service> Services { get; set; }
}

public class Service
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Duration { get; set; }
}

public class MergingClass
{
    public List<Slot> MergeSlots()
    {
        var mergedList = new List<Slot>();
        var list1 = new List<Slot>
                        {
                            new Slot
                                {
                                    Start = new DateTime(2018, 11, 1, 8, 0, 0),
                                    End = new DateTime(2018, 11, 1, 11, 0, 0),
                                    Services = new List<Service>
                                                   {
                                                       new Service
                                                           {
                                                               Duration = 20,
                                                               Id = 1
                                                           }
                                                   }
                                },
                            new Slot
                                {
                                    Start = new DateTime(2018, 11, 1, 12, 0, 0),
                                    End = new DateTime(2018, 11, 1, 16, 0, 0),
                                    Services = new List<Service>
                                                   {
                                                       new Service
                                                           {
                                                               Duration = 20,
                                                               Id = 1
                                                           }
                                                   }
                                }
                        };

        var list2 = new List<Slot>
                          {
                              new Slot
                                  {
                                      Start = new DateTime(2018, 11, 1, 8, 0, 0),
                                      End = new DateTime(2018, 11, 1, 11, 0, 0),
                                      Services = new List<Service>
                                                     {
                                                         new Service
                                                             {
                                                                 Duration = 30,
                                                                 Id = 2
                                                             }
                                                     }
                                  },
                              new Slot
                                  {
                                      Start = new DateTime(2018, 11, 1, 12, 0, 0),
                                      End = new DateTime(2018, 11, 1, 18, 0, 0),
                                      Services = new List<Service>
                                                     {
                                                         new Service
                                                             {
                                                                 Duration = 30,
                                                                 Id = 2
                                                             }
                                                     }
                                  }
                          };
        return mergedList;
    }
}
```

Start and End is block of time, that will be divided by service duration (service duration is int representing minutes).

So i have 2 lists (for 2 differenet services), and I need to merge them by Start and End dates into 3rd list (mergedList).

Method MergeSlots in this case should return:

```
mergedList = new List<Slot>
                    {
                        new Slot
                            {
                                Start = new DateTime(2018, 11, 1, 8, 0, 0),
                                End = new DateTime(2018, 11, 1, 11, 0, 0),
                                Services = new List<Service>
                                            {
                                                new Service
                                                    {
                                                        Duration = 20,
                                                        Id = 1
                                                    },
                                                new Service
                                                    {
                                                        Duration = 30,
                                                        Id = 2
                                                    }
                                            }
                            },
                        new Slot
                            {
                                Start = new DateTime(2018, 11, 1, 12, 0, 0),
                                End = new DateTime(2018, 11, 1, 16, 0, 0),
                                Services = new List<Service>
                                            {
                                                new Service
                                                    {
                                                        Duration = 20,
                                                        Id = 1
                                                    },
                                                new Service
                                                    {
                                                        Duration = 30,
                                                        Id = 2
                                                    }
                                            }
                            },
                        new Slot
                            {
                                Start = new DateTime(2018, 11, 1, 16, 0, 0),
                                End = new DateTime(2018, 11, 1, 18, 0, 0),
                                Services = new List<Service>
                                            {
                                                new Service
                                                    {
                                                        Duration = 30,
                                                        Id = 2
                                                    }
                                            }
                            }
                    };
```

Of course, both lists of slots come from a system that I can not influence and they will be different each time.

I tried to do it step by step, but solution is huge and ugly and error prone:

```
foreach (var slot in list2)
{
    var slotWithStartInList1 = list1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Start <= slot.Start && x.End > slot.Start);
    if (slotWithStartInList1 != null)
    {
        if (slot.Start == slotWithStartInList1.Start)
        {
            if (slot.End == slotWithStartInList1.End)
            {
                slot.Services.AddRange(slotWithStartInList1.Services);
                mergedList.Add(slot);
                continue;
            }

            if (slot.End < slotWithStartInList1.End)
            {
                slot.Services.AddRange(slotWithStartInList1.Services);
                slotWithStartInList1.Start = slot.End;

                mergedList.Add(slot);
                mergedList.Add(slotWithStartInList1);
                continue;
            }

            slotWithStartInList1.Services.AddRange(slot.Services);
            slot.Start = slotWithStartInList1.End;

            mergedList.Add(slotWithStartInList1);
            mergedList.Add(slot);
            continue;
        }

        if (slot.End == slotWithStartInList1.End)
        {
            slotWithStartInList1.End = slot.Start;
            slot.Services.AddRange(slotWithStartInList1.Services);

            mergedList.Add(slotWithStartInList1);
            mergedList.Add(slot);
            continue;
        }

        if (slot.End > slotWithStartInList1.End)
        {
            var tempSlot = new Slot
                               {
                                   Start = slot.Start,
                                   End = slotWithStartInList1.End,
                                   Services = new List<Services>()
                               };
            tempSlot.Services.AddRange(slotWithStartInList1.Services);
            tempSlot.Services.AddRange(slot.Services);

            slotWithStartInList1.End = tempSlot.Start;
            slot.Start = tempSlot.End;

            mergedList.Add(tempSlot);
            mergedList.Add(slot);
            mergedList.Add(slotWithStartInList1);
            continue;
        }

        var tempSlot2 = new Slot
                           {
                               Start = slotWithStartInList1.Start,
                               End = slot.Start,
                               Services = new List<Services>()
                           };
        tempSlot2.Services.AddRange(slotWithStartInList1.Services);

        slot.Services.AddRange(slotWithStartInList1.Services);
        slotWithStartInList1.Start = slot.End;

        mergedList.Add(tempSlot2);
        mergedList.Add(slot);
        mergedList.Add(slotWithStartInList1);
        continue;
    }

    var slotWithEndInList1 = list1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Start < slot.End && x.End >= slot.End);
    if (slotWithEndInList1 != null)
    {
        if (slot.End == slotWithEndInList1.End)
        {
            slot.End = slotWithEndInList1.End;
            slotWithEndInList1.Services.AddRange(slot.Services);

            mergedList.Add(slot);
            mergedList.Add(slotWithEndInList1);

            continue;
        }

        var tempSlot2 = new Slot
                            {
                                Start = slotWithEndInList1.Start,
                                End = slot.End,
                                Services = new List<Services>()
                            };
        tempSlot2.Services.AddRange(slotWithEndInList1.Services);
        tempSlot2.Services.AddRange(slot.Services);

        slot.End = tempSlot2.Start;
        slotWithEndInList1.Start = tempSlot2.End;

        mergedList.Add(tempSlot2);
        mergedList.Add(slot);
        mergedList.Add(slotWithEndInList1);
        continue;
    }

    mergedList.Add(slot);
}

foreach (var slot in list1)
{
    if (mergedList.Any(x => x.Start == slot.Start))
    {
        continue;
    }

    mergedList.Add(slot);
}

return mergedList;
```

I can add few private methods to avoid code duplication, but I wonder if there is better (cleaner, shorter) way to accomplish my goal?

Maybe some linq extensions?

Comment: Could you explain what is the logic of the merge operation? In other words: what do you mean by merge? There can be different views: overwrite from left to right, from right to left, ignore, sum, extend, etc...

Comment: Can you share the rest of the file as well? How are the functions used? In what place?

Answer (score 4):

You have a lot of code to carefully, almost surgically, merge records from list2 into list1 based on a sorted order.  Why not just (1) quickly merge the 2 lists without regards to order, followed immediately by (2) custom ordering?  Something short like:

```
mergedList = list1.ToList().Union(list2).ToList();
mergedList = mergedList.OrderBy(x => x.StartTime).ThenBy(x => x.EndTime).ToList();
```

Also, I think `Slot` is too generic a name.  I suggest `TimeSlot` instead.

You have no real checks when adding a time slot that `Start` occurs before `End`.  You may also want to make sure all `DateTime` values are based on the same `DateTimeKind`.  There is nothing in your code that prevents one time slot based on Utc and another based on Local.

`Duration` is an int representing minutes.  This is ripe for confusion.  You could rename the variable to be `DurationInMinutes`, but I would recommend using a `TimeSpan` instead.  This makes the code more understandable with:

```
Duration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
```

Later you will probably be using that `Duration` with some conditional or other calculation with another `DateTime` and a `TimeSpan` is a great fit for that.

**UPDATE MORE SUGGESTIONS**

You are interested in a custom sort for your time slots, but I am guessing you want that sort always.  You might want to consider making `TimeSlot` implement `IEquatable<TimeSlot>` and `IComparable<TimeSlot>`.  You will need to add some methods to help out there, such as `Equals`, `CompareTo`, and `GetHashCode`.

[IEquatable link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)

[IComparable link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)